# How to set only time part of a DateTime

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I need to set datetime variable but it's time part must be 3:00:00 AM.
For example if i call `getdate()` now i'll get `1/20/2014 3:52:03 AM`. I need to set it to `1/20/2014 3:00:00 AM`.
Does anybody have a good snippet for that or any ideas how to do it right? would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of ways to do this - reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might give you more ideas

```
Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now()
Dim threeAmDate As DateTime = New DateTime(someDate.Year, _
                                           someDate.Month, _
                                           someDate.Day, _
                                           3, _  'hours 
                                           0, _  'minutes
                                           0, _  'seconds
                                           0)    'milliseconds
Console.WriteLine(threeAmDate)
```

Answer (score 7):

The constructor for the DateTime allows you to specify hours, minutes and seconds as well as the usual day month and year.

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim myDate = New DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 3, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is old... But I came across having the same question.

```
Dim dt As New DateTime(_DateTo.Ticks + _TimeTo.Ticks)
```

--> Both '_DateTo' and/or '_TimeTo' could be Timespan or Datetime objects.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Label1.Text = DateAndTime.Today & "    " & TimeOfDay
```

you can put this in a label or anything and you can change time of day to "3:00:00"